# First Generator Model Tutorial for Acceleo

Tags: acceleo

I am new to Eclipse and Acceleo, and I have been trying to complete the First Generator Model Tutorial.  I am using Juno 4.2 and Acceleo 3.3.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. I created an Accelo projece with a UML Metamodel and Generate
   Type Class.
2. I added the provided code for the generate file, and
   put the [comment @main/] below the template line.
3. I made changes to the MANIFEST file. Under the Bundle SymbolicName, I added singleton:=true. I added the files for runtime, added all the necessary plugins and under extensions, I added the UML generate and dynamic package.
4. I then created a new Java Project, and then selected UML Model and made it a package. I then created a class by right clicking on the package, selecting New Child and then class.
5. I go to launch the generate file. I selected the uml model and the target as the src file under the new Java Project. It says it is launching it, but I can not see the generated file, or it is not actually generating it.

I would really appreciate any help or feedback.  I am really stuck on this!

Comment: Hi, AxA's answer below is one possibility. Otherwise we'll need a little more info : do you have anything in the error log (Window > Show View > Error Log)? Do you have a [file] block in your template? Does your model contain an element of the type required by your "@main" template?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also quite new to Acceleo, but I can give it a try:
do you have a [file] construct in your generate.mtl file? Because without it Acceleo doesn't generate any file.

This is an example of usage of the [file] in the generate.mtl file. It creates a myFile.txt file with a class name inside:

```
[comment encoding = UTF-8 /]
[module genAFile('http:///org/eclipse/uml.... etc ')/]

[template public genAFile(aClass : Class)]
    [file ('myFile.txt', false, 'UTF-8')]
        [aClass.name/]
    [/file]
[/template]
```

Hope it helps